# $x_n \rightharpoonup x$ then $\sigma_n= \frac{x_1+x_2+...+x_n}{n} \rightharpoonup x$

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence, banach-spaces

This is the exercise 3.2 of Brezis book. Let $E$ a Banach space and let $(x_n)$ be a sequence such that $x_n\rightharpoonup x$ in the weak topology $\sigma(E,E^*)$. Set $\sigma_n=\frac{x_1+x_2+...+x_n}{n}$. Prove that $\sigma_n\rightharpoonup x$ in the weak topology $\sigma(E,E^*)$.

I want to show that for
every $f\in E^* \quad |<f,\sigma_n>-<f,x>| \rightarrow 0$.

$|<f,\sigma_n>-<f,x>|=\displaystyle{\left| \frac{f(x_1-x)}{n}+\frac{f(x_2-x)}{n}+...+\frac{f(x_n-x)}{n}\right|}$ and I don't know how to continue, I was thinking about $f(x_n-x)$ is bounded but how can I use this? and the most important fact that $|<f,x_n>-<f,x>| \rightarrow 0$. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Essentially this is just the fact that the [Césaro sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ces%C3%A0ro_summation) converges to the sequence limit for the sequence $(f(x_n))_{n\in\mathbb N}$ for every fixed $f\in E^*$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose $|\langle f, x_n \rangle - \langle f, x \rangle| < \varepsilon$ for all $n \ge  N$.

Then for $m \ge N$, split $\sigma_m$ into two parts:

$$\sigma_m = \frac{x_1 + \dots + x_N}{m} + \frac{x_{N + 1} + \dots + x_m}{m}.$$

As $m \to \infty$, the first half the expression goes to $0$ because the numerator is fixed. For the other half, you can use the bound $|\langle f, x_n \rangle - \langle f, x \rangle| < \varepsilon$ from the beginning.

Comment: This is unnecessary. Just apply Cesaro's theroem to the real sequence $ \langle f, x_i \rangle$ The question  is entirely trivial.